# Session behavior in events sent from Azure IoT Hub

Tags: azure, session, azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-iot-hub

We're developing an application based on Azures Edge runtime. Our application sends messages upstream to the cloud, to an IoT hub that in turn has routes defined that sends to different service bus queues. Here's a simple image:

[image]

On one of these queues we care about *sessions*, meaning we need to bulk receive and act on each event in order in our function. The problem we've noticed is that when our application produces events in quick succession this happens:

1. First event arrives
2. Model fetched from db that corresponds to event data
3. Model is updated
4. Model is placed on outgoing Cosmos binding
5. Before the cosmos out binding is triggered, the next event arrives, keeping the function on
6. Model fetched from db that corresponds to event data *before* the previous events data has been persisted, meaning we act on already stale data

I looked into service bus queue sessions, which seems to solve this, but sessions are incompatible with IoT Hub. We are also not creating the message placed on the queue, we are creating an IoT Hub message and the hub in turn creates a service bus message, so the session handling is out of our control.

How could I handle this pattern without the session feature of the service bus queue?

Comment: Are the events that are coming and you try to order are coming from the same device? so you expect that messages coming from the same device are processed sequentially or all the events from all of the devices should be processes sequentially?

Comment: All messages are from the same device, and we have a clear start and end to the sequence. The messages we need to process sequentially will arrive on the same service bus queue. We have solved this temporarily by not using the out binding of the function and instead implementing the Cosmos Node SDK to write and block during write, before the function exits.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted to suggest as option A. Option B maybe could be that instead of functions and Service Bus Queues you route the message to the Event Hub. The number of partitions should match the number of partitions with IoT Hub. There is a hashing function that guarantees the delivery to the same partition always from the same deviceID. Now if you implement 'by hand' message processing from EH, and maintaining offsets and sequence numbers manually, you can pretty much control when the next sequence of the messages will be processed, and therefore maintain the consistency.